# http_response_code issue with method PUT

Tags: php, rest

This issue is simple to understand, I'm coding an API and trying give a HTTP response, I'm testing on [resttest](http://resttesttest.com/).

**The issue:**
I'm geting an error when method is PUT or DELETE trying return a HTTP response code over 400.

Here is my code:

**.httacces:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ webroot/index.php [QSA,L]
```

**Here webroot/index.php:**

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");

http_response_code(400);
?>
```

just remembering, this same code works if method is GET or POST or if the code is under 400.

Comment: `http_response_code()` should just work, so if it doesn't, the problem is likely somewhere else which could be both code or configuration. Share the actual code.

Comment: Like it's super common for instance for frameworks to reset the status code. It could simply overwrite what you set it to earlier.

Comment: I've made a lot of tests and I will fully edit this question and will be a lot more simple for you undertand whats happening.. just give 5 minutes.

Comment: Hey Daniel, is that literally all your code? Or is this code embedded in a framework?

Comment: Would you happen to have this somewhere public? It's unconventional but it will allow me to quickly take a look

Comment: My email is on my profile :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying this out...

I think the REST testing tool you are using will use CORS to figure out if it's allowed to make requests.

The issue is that for any non-safe HTTP request (`PUT`, `POST`, `DELETE`, etc) CORS will first do what's called a 'pre-flight' request.

This pre-flight request is actually an `OPTIONS` request with several CORS headers and basically asks the server, "am I allowed to execute this next http method?".

Your pre-flight fails, because the `OPTIONS` request will result in a `400 Bad request`. As a result the 'real' request will never be executed.

Comment: Make a lot of sense.. what would I do?

Comment: worcked! Theres something that I can do to OPTIONS method thow 400 error?

Comment: Yes, you did throw a HTTP 400 before, and it gave you an error in the browser.